# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getLastRow')

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, properties, null, typeerror

I have this script that serves as a Birthday Reminder. The script is giving an error as shown after it

```
function main() {
  // Load the sheet that contains the birthdays.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Birthdays");

  // Get the last row in the sheet that has data.
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Load data in the first two columns from the second row till the last row. 
  // Remember: The first row has column headers so we don’t want to load it.
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows - 1, 2).getValues();

  // Use a for loop to process each row of data
  for(var index in range) {

    // For each row, get the person’s name and their birthday
    var row = range[index];
    var name = row[0];
    var birthday = row[1];

    // Check if the person’s birthday is today
    if(isBirthdayToday(birthday)) {
      //If yes, send an email reminder
      emailReminder(name);
    }
  }
}

// Check if a person’s birthday is today
function isBirthdayToday(birthday) {
  // If birthday is a string, convert it to date
  if(typeof birthday === "string")
    birthday = new Date(birthday);
  var today = new Date();
  if((today.getDate() === birthday.getDate()) &&
      (today.getMonth() === birthday.getMonth())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Function to send the email reminder
function emailReminder(name) {
  var subject = "Birthday reminder: " + name;
  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var body = "It is " + name + "'s birthday today.";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

This is the error I get
Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getLastRow')
main    @ Code.gs:6

It is not my script but found it.
Don´t know how to correct the error.
If someone can help.

Comment: You do have a sheet/tab titled "Birthdays", yes? You can also try `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` instead of `.getActive()` if this is a standalone script, versus a script attached to the Sheet.

Comment: Yes, I have a sheet titled 'Birthdays' and the idea is to attach it to the script. Don't know if it gets attached just by mentioning it in the script or any other way.

Comment: I changed to what you suggested:
function main() {
  // Load the sheet that contains the birthdays.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Birthdays");
But same error

Comment: Check for spaces in the name of the sheet

Comment: It is a one word name 'Birthdays'  No spaces

Comment: Did you create the script from within the sheet or is it a Apps Script file you created in your Drive?

Comment: There might be spaces at the end. In any case, that is the answer: The name doesn't match. No other answer.  Figure out why. Change it to a simpler name like `S1`, while being carefulll to not add spaces at the end or before the actual string.